# R sorting and grouping problems

Tags: python, r, dataframe, r-markdown

I have this sample dataset.
[image]
s

I'm trying to filter to the earliest 'started_at' entry by 'rideable_type'. Here is my code.

```r
   test %>% select(started_at, rideable_type) %>%
     arrange(rideable_type) %>%
     filter(min(started_at)) %>%
     group_by(rideable_type)
```

I'm getting the following error.

```
    Error in `filter()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = test`.
✖ Input `..1$ride_id` must be a logical vector, not a character.
Backtrace:
 1. ... %>% group_by(test$rideable_type)
 4. dplyr:::filter.data.frame(., test, min(test$started_at))
Error in filter(., test, min(test$started_at)) :
✖ Input `..1$ride_id` must be a logical vector, not a character.
```

This is the trackeback.

```
    16.
stop(fallback)
15.
signal_abort(cnd, .file)
14.
abort(bullets, call = error_call, parent = skip_internal_condition(e))
13.
(function (e)
{
local_error_context(dots = dots, .index = env_filter$current_expression,
mask = mask) ...
12.
signalCondition(cnd)
11.
signal_abort(cnd, .file)
10.
abort(class = c(class, "dplyr:::internal_error"), dplyr_error_data = data)
9.
dplyr_internal_error("dplyr:::filter_incompatible_type", list(
index = 1L, column_name = "ride_id", result = c("98D355D9A9852BE9",
"04706CA7F5BD25EE", "42178E850B92597A", "6B93C46E8F5B114C",
"466943353EAC8022", "AC1F67BDCDDD5988", "A5BD5A4FD53D5414", ...
8.
mask$eval_all_filter(dots, env_filter)
7.
withCallingHandlers({
mask$eval_all_filter(dots, env_filter)
}, error = function(e) {
local_error_context(dots = dots, .index = env_filter$current_expression, ...
6.
filter_eval(dots, mask = mask, error_call = error_call)
5.
filter_rows(.data, ..., caller_env = caller_env())
4.
filter.data.frame(., test, min(test$started_at))
3.
filter(., test, min(test$started_at))
2.
group_by(., test$rideable_type)
1.
select(test, started_at, rideable_type) %>% arrange(test$rideable_type) %>%
filter(test, min(test$started_at)) %>% group_by(test$rideable_type)
```

I'm fairly new to R but I noticed the error referenced the ride_id column as part of the problem, but that col isn't included in the select clause.

Comment: Can you please provide sample data to work with via `dput` command, it will be much easier to run the code and diagnose it.

Answer (score 0):

could you please try the below code

```r
  test %>% select(started_at, rideable_type) %>%
     group_by(rideable_type) %>%
     filter(as.POSIXct(started_at)==min(as.POSIXct(started_at)))
```

Comment: That worked. I thought as.POSIXct might have been an issue, but I never got it to work. What really throws me is the group coming first. I guess I was thinking in SQL terms where it would be at the end.  Any explanation on the ride_id showing up in the error message?Thank you

Comment: Its hard to say about the error, since i don't have the actual data.